# Select from inherited table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, inheritance

I have this inheritance in my database and I need to use a SELECT query and INSERT query to it.

I can't seem to pull this off.

It's about the Item and it's inheritances.

[image]

Comment: Insert into what? What kind of results are you expecting to insert? What have you tried?

Comment: I think you are asking this : how to insert data into inherited tables , You should insert into Armor,Potion and Weapon tables. And you can select from them. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani yeah that is exactly what I am asking. I might have said it a little bad but it comes down to what you said.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but I think you would be better off without those individual tables. Instead, you should just have a single extra field in the item table for "effect" which could include, say, extra damage (weapons), extra defense (armour) or other effects (whatever potions give). Alternatively, a single "item effects" table that includes all item effects if there are multiple effects.

Comment: Resolved: I needed to use a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be helpful?

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

I don't know if i've understood your question but, you want to insert some values into a table selecting from an another table.